# When v-for array created by computed option changs, the DOM doesn't change accordingly

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Recently, I've encountered a problem that caused by the computed option of vuejs.

Firstly, I use v-for to loop for an array (soloColImgs) which is created by the computed option.

my HTML

```
  <div class="show-box" v-for="item in soloColImgs" track-by="$index">
                <img v-bind:src="item.imgUrl"/>
                <a v-bind:href="item.itemUrl" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
```

my JS

```
   //...
   computed: {
   soloColImgs :function(){
           //....
    },

   methods: {
      change:function(){
              this.soloColImgs.pop();
           }
      }
```

Secondly, I change the array (soloColImgs) by using `pop()` or `splice()` etc...When I look into the console, the array can change accordingly, however, the **DOM** does't change at all. It would be greatful if anyone can help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a computed property is that its determined solely by the function that defines it. You cannot change it directly, you must change it by acting on the dependencies. The dependencies are the properties that are used to calculate the returned value.

Comment: Thank you! I've found out exactly the same thing just now. And I've solved my problem by changing the dependencies, the same idea as described in your answer ; )